# Всё, нашёл(,) что искал!

Tags: запятые

Простите за детсадовский вопрос, но не могу понять, нужна ли запятая. Вроде можно заменить на *"нашёл потерянное".* Хотя обычно вроде замена на обстоятельство образа действия отменяет запятую, с другой стороны, потенциальное придаточное тесно примыкает к сказуемому. Как правильно в этом случае?

Comment: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB

Comment: Да видел я это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Всё, нашёл что искал!***

Пример без запятой:  *Отец, прищурившись, недолго рассматривал колышущуюся полутьму, потом **нашел что искал**, подхватил меня, внес во двор и тут же поставил на какой-то высокий верстак.*  [Захар Прилепин. Лес (2010)]. Здесь ударением выделены однородные сказуемые, поэтому дополнительно обособить оборот нет возможности.

Оборот может относиться к теме неразложимых сочетаний http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Их обособление в общем случае факультативно, Розенталь говорит о том, что  в зависимости от контекста возможна различная пунктуация.

В конечном счете **всё определяется структурой предложения и расстановкой ударений.**

***Всё, нашёл что искАл!*** В этом предложении логическое ударение делается на обороте, но не делается на сказуемом, соответственно паузы нет.

Сравнить: ***Всё, я нашЁл, что искАл!***  То есть достаточно немного распространить предложение, и уже на сказуемом можно поставить ударение, обособление возможно.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! А я делаю ударение на "нашёл", но при этом запятую всё равно не хочется ставить. Не совсем понял: *Здесь ударением выделены однородные сказуемые...* и последний пример, где тоже на оба сказуемых ударения. У вас пунктуация получается разная.

Comment: 1) Артем, вы можете поставить ударение на "нашёл", но  вряд ли у вас получится поставить ударение на трех словах: ВсЁ, нашЁл, что искАл! А это значит между вторым и третьим словом нет паузы. 2) Об однородных сказуемых. Как известно, на каждый из однородных членов падает ударение (так выглядит перечислительная интонация). Однородные сказуемые могут иметь зависимые слова, ударение может падать на глагол или на зависимое слово, но двух ударений там не может быть.  Поэтому нежелательно разделять паузой глагол и зависимый оборот, иначе однородный ряд сказуемых не будет обозначен

Comment: Да, я без паузы произношу! Пауза только после "всё".